# Como fazer animações dinâmicas com CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css3, animação

Sei fazer animações com transition, rotate + :hover ou desencadeando mudança de classe com JS.

Mas e se eu quiser uma animação em CSS3 que ao ser renderizada ela faça mais de um movimento sem ficar 'limitada à um par de chaves'?

ps: No momento procuro soluções que dispensem o uso de jQuery ou qualquer outra lib. Por motivo de deixar a aplicação mais "crua" e leve.

Comment: Desculpe, não ficou muito claro. O que seria uma animação dinâmica?

Comment: @rnxn Encontrei o que eu queria: se chama keyframe

Comment: @ropbla9 Se tiver disposição, compartilhe o que descobriu em uma resposta! Não conhecia esse keyframe, mas após uma olhada rápida me pareceu bastante interessante... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apenas complementando o que já encontrou ai para a galera que não conhece ainda.

Animações em CSS3 podem ser criadas usando a propriedade [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), que a propósito é uma propriedade muito poderosa.

Ela pode ser definida da seguinte maneira:

```
@keyframes nome_da_animacao {
    /* Passos */
    from {
        /* Estado inicial */
    }
    to {
        /* Estado final */
    }
}
```

Você ainda pode definir os passos para a animação em porcentagem ao invés de `from` e `to`

```
@keyframes nome_da_animacao {
    /* Passos */
    0% {
        /* Estado inicial */
    }
    50% {
        /* Estado aos 50% da animação */
    }
    100% {
        /* Estado final */
    }
}
```

Logo depois que criar sua animação, para adicionar ela ao elemento basta usar a propriedade [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

```
#elemento {
    /* nome_da_animacao + propriedades */
    animation: nome_da_animacao 1s infinite;
}
```

De acordo com a documentação no MDN a propriedade `animation` tem as seguintes configurações:

- [animation-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name): Nome que você deseja dar a animação;
- [animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-dura): Duração da animação;
- [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timi): Método de animação que deseja usar (ease, ease-in-out, etc.);
- [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-dela): Delay até o inicio da animação;
- [animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count): Quantas vezes a animação vai rodar;
- [animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction): Determina se a animação deverá seguir um ciclo constante ou voltar os passos dela de modo reverso;
- [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode): Como a animação deverá se comportar antes e depois de ser executada;
- [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state): Usado para pausar ou rodar uma animação;

Infelizmente ainda é necessário o uso de prefixos para que funcione bem na maioria dos browsers modernos; Tanto na declaração da animação, como quando for aplicar ao elemento.

Segue um exemplo de animação usando o `@keyframes`: http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/kLrzpz6x/embedded/result

Excelente artigo no CSS Tricks falando a respeito: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax